# Is there a simple tool to flatten a wsdl file?

Tags: wsdl

I have nested WSDL that I want to make flat. The wsdl imports xsd files that in turn include other files and so on. I like to flatten the whole thing into one file in order to feed it into a tool that isn't capable of doing the imports/includes.
Is there a simple tool (maybe commandline) that I can use for it? I tried using xsltproc/xmllint but those don't know anything about wsdl include.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm very late, but just in case anyone else will need it, here's a (admittedly very dirty) code snippet I arranged (by taking half-working pieces of code I found in various places and adding some fixes). This requires .NET 4.5 to work, but will flatten remote WSDL URLs nicely. It probably won't cover all cases, but it is working for me in last 2 years.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services.Discovery;
using System.Xml;

namespace FlattenXml {

   internal class Program {
      private static XmlDocument m_MapDoc;
      private static string m_DocPath;
      private static XmlDocument m_FlattenDocument = new XmlDocument();
      private static string m_ServiceUri;
      private static Dictionary<string, XmlElement> m_Elements = new Dictionary<string, XmlElement>();

      private static void Main(string[] args) {
         if (args == null || args.Length == 0) {
            Program.usage();
         } else {
            if (args != null && args.Length == 1 && (args[0] == "-h" || args[0] == "-?")) {
               Program.usage();
            } else {
               if (args != null && args.Length == 2) {
                  Program.m_DocPath = args[1];
                  Program.m_ServiceUri = args[0];
                  DiscoveryClientProtocol client = new DiscoveryClientProtocol();
                  client.DiscoverAny(Program.m_ServiceUri);
                  client.ResolveAll();
                  Program.m_DocPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Program.m_DocPath);
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(Program.m_DocPath);
                  string mapFile = Path.Combine(Program.m_DocPath, "map.xml");
                  client.WriteAll(Program.m_DocPath, mapFile);
                  flattenDocuments(mapFile);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private static void usage() {
         Console.WriteLine("Usage: flattenxml [Service Wsdl URL] [Output Folder]");
         Console.WriteLine("Example: flattenxml http://localhost/Daenet.TrackingService/TrackingService.svc Out");
      }

      private static void flattenDocuments(string mapFile) {
         string rootDocumentName = Program.getRootDocumentFile(mapFile);
         Program.m_FlattenDocument = Program.flattenDocument(Path.Combine(Program.m_DocPath, rootDocumentName));
         Program.m_FlattenDocument.Save("FlattenDocument.wsdl");
      }

      private static string getRootDocumentFile(string mapFile) {
         XmlDocument mapDoc = new XmlDocument();
         mapDoc.Load(mapFile);
         Program.m_MapDoc = mapDoc;
         foreach (XmlElement el in mapDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.OfType<XmlElement>()) {
            if (el.Attributes["url"].Value == Program.m_ServiceUri || el.Attributes["url"].Value == Program.m_ServiceUri + "?wsdl") {
               return el.Attributes["filename"].Value;
            }
         }
         throw new ApplicationException("Root document annot be determined.");
      }

      private static XmlDocument flattenDocument(string rootDocumentName) {
         XmlDocument unflattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
         unflattenDoc.Load(rootDocumentName);
         return Program.importElements(unflattenDoc.DocumentElement);
      }

      private static XmlDocument importElements(XmlElement schemaEl) {
         XmlElement root = schemaEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
         Program.importElement(root, schemaEl);
         XmlDocument flattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
         flattenDoc.LoadXml(root.FirstChild.OuterXml);
         return flattenDoc;
      }

      private static void importExternalElement(XmlElement typeParentEl, XmlElement typeEl) {
         if (typeEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "import" || typeEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "include") {
            string importingDocName = Program.getImportingDocName(typeEl);
            if (importingDocName != null && !Program.m_Elements.ContainsKey(importingDocName)) {
               Program.addComment(typeParentEl, typeEl);
               XmlDocument unflattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
               unflattenDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Program.m_DocPath, importingDocName));
               Program.m_Elements.Add(importingDocName, null);
               XmlElement importedEl = typeParentEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
               Program.importElement(importedEl, unflattenDoc.DocumentElement);

               // B: for WSDL, inner "definitions" and "policy" elements should be skipped. For all other cases (i.e. XSD) everything should be included
               if (typeParentEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "definitions" && typeParentEl.LocalName == importedEl.FirstChild.LocalName) {
                  Program.mergeNamespaces(typeParentEl, importedEl.FirstChild as XmlElement);
                  foreach (XmlElement cEl in importedEl.FirstChild.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()) {
                     // B: skip policy definitions from internal WSDLs
                     if (cEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "policy") {
                        continue;
                     }
                     XmlElement cEl2 = cEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
                     cEl2.InnerXml = cEl.OuterXml;
                     typeParentEl.InsertBefore(cEl2.FirstChild, typeEl);
                  }
               } else {
                  typeParentEl.InsertBefore(importedEl.FirstChild, typeEl);
               }
               Program.m_Elements[importingDocName] = importedEl;
            }
            typeParentEl.RemoveChild(typeEl);
            return;
         }
         throw new ArgumentException();
      }

      private static XmlElement importElement(XmlElement typeParentEl, XmlElement typeEl) {
         XmlElement resultingElement;
         if (typeEl.ChildNodes.Count > 0) {
            XmlElement newEl = typeParentEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
            newEl.InnerXml = typeEl.OuterXml;
            if (typeEl.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Count<XmlElement>() > 0) {
               newEl.FirstChild.InnerXml = "";
               foreach (XmlElement child in typeEl.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()) {
                  if (child.LocalName.ToLower() == "import" || child.LocalName.ToLower() == "include") {
                     XmlElement impEl = newEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
                     impEl.InnerXml = child.OuterXml;
                     XmlElement x = newEl.FirstChild.AppendChild(impEl.FirstChild) as XmlElement;
                     Program.importExternalElement(newEl.FirstChild as XmlElement, x);
                  } else {
                     Program.importElement(newEl.FirstChild as XmlElement, child);
                  }
               }
            }
            resultingElement = Program.appendElement(typeParentEl, newEl.FirstChild);
         } else {
            if (typeParentEl.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Count((XmlElement e) => e.LocalName == typeEl.LocalName) >= 1) {
            }
            resultingElement = Program.appendElement(typeParentEl, typeEl);
         }
         return resultingElement;
      }

      private static XmlElement appendElement(XmlElement parentEl, XmlNode childNode) {
         XmlElement newEl = parentEl.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("a");
         newEl.InnerXml = childNode.OuterXml;
         return parentEl.AppendChild(newEl.FirstChild) as XmlElement;
      }

      private static XmlDocument loadUnflattenDocument(string importingDoc) {
         XmlDocument unflattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
         unflattenDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Program.m_DocPath, importingDoc));
         XmlDocument flattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
         return unflattenDoc;
      }

      private static XmlDocument loadDocumentFromImportNode(XmlElement importEl) {
         string importingDoc = Program.getImportingDocName(importEl);
         XmlDocument unflattenDoc = new XmlDocument();
         unflattenDoc.Load(Path.Combine(Program.m_DocPath, importingDoc));
         return unflattenDoc;
      }

      private static string getImportingDocName(XmlElement importEl) {
         return Program.getImportingDocName(Program.getImportingDocReference(importEl));
      }

      private static string getImportingDocReference(XmlElement importEl) {
         if (importEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "import" || importEl.LocalName.ToLower() == "include") {
            if (importEl.Attributes["location"] != null) {
               return importEl.Attributes["location"].Value;
            } else if (importEl.Attributes["schemaLocation"] != null) {
               return importEl.Attributes["schemaLocation"].Value;
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid node, ignored:");
         Console.WriteLine(importEl.OuterXml);
         return null;
      }

      private static string getImportingDocName(string docReference) {
         if (docReference == null) return null;

         // NOTE: [B] the following fix required .NET 4.5, because before .NET 4.5. the URLs were not URLEncoded, which was wrong. The extra check below allows it run with .NET 3.5 or later
         var docReferenceRaw = Uri.UnescapeDataString(docReference);
         XmlElement refEl = Program.m_MapDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault((XmlElement el) => el.Attributes["url"].Value == docReference || el.Attributes["url"].Value == docReferenceRaw);
         if (refEl != null) {
            return refEl.Attributes["filename"].Value;
         }
         throw new ApplicationException("Mapping error");
      }

      private static void addComment(XmlElement parentEl, XmlElement importEl) {
         var location = Program.getImportingDocReference(importEl);
         var path = location == null ? "" : new Uri(Program.getImportingDocReference(importEl)).PathAndQuery;
         XmlComment commentEl = parentEl.OwnerDocument.CreateComment("Begin \"" + path + "\"");
         parentEl.InsertBefore(commentEl, importEl);
         XmlComment commentEl2 = parentEl.OwnerDocument.CreateComment("End \"" + path + "\"");
         parentEl.InsertAfter(commentEl2, importEl);
      }

      private static void mergeNamespaces(XmlElement el1, XmlElement el2) {
         foreach (XmlAttribute attr in new List<XmlAttribute>(el2.Attributes.OfType<XmlAttribute>())) {
            if (el1.Attributes.OfType<XmlAttribute>().Count((XmlAttribute e) => e.Name == attr.Name) == 0) {
               el1.Attributes.Append(attr);
            }
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [flatten-wsdl.py](https://github.com/sebmartin/FlatWSDL) would help to create singleWsdl file. It 's a small python script that will fetch WSDL from URL and flatten it by importing all referenced parts (i.e `xsd:import`)

You can use it like this and it will generate flatten.wsdl file

```
python flatten-wsdl.py http://URL/SOME-WSDL-WITH-INLINE-SCHEMA?wsdl -f flatten.wsdl
```